# Xhtml slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

```
<html xmlns:t ="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:time">
<head>
<style>
.time
{
behavior: url(#default#time2);}
.text
{
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #003366;}
.palat {
FONT-SIZE: 14pt; LEFT: 80px; COLOR: green; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 250px}
.teatru {
FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 16pt; LEFT: 80px; WIDTH: 20px; COLOR: white; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 180px; WRITING-MODE: tb-rl}
.uaic {
FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 24pt; LEFT: 80px; COLOR: white; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 300px}
</style>
<?import namespace="t" implementation="#default#time2">
<title>XHTML+TIME</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<SCRIPT>
function modifica()
{ 
if(!secv.currTimeState.isActive)
{ secv.beginElement() }
 if(Math.round(cronom.value)!=Math.round(secv.currTimeState.segmentTime))
{ secv.seekSegmentTime(cronom.value) }
}
</SCRIPT>
<body>
<h1 align="center" class="text">SLIDE-SHOW
</h1>
<div align="center">
<BUTTON onclick=modifica()>Incepe slide-show</BUTTON>
<div style="MARGIN-TOP: 10px; BACKGROUND: white; WIDTH: 200px; HEIGHT: 200px">
<t:seq id=secv begin = "indefinite" dur = "12" repeatCount = "1">
<t:par dur = "3" timeAction = "display">
<!--<SPAN class="time palat">Palatul culturii din Iasi
<t:animate attributeName = "fontSize" from = "14px" to = "24pt" dur = "3" fill = "hold">
</t:animate>
</SPAN>-->
<t:img src ="p1.JPG"></t:img>
</t:par>
<t:par dur = "3" timeAction = "display">
<!--<SPAN class="time teatru">Teatrul National "Vasile Alecsandri"
<t:animate attributeName = "left" from = "80px" to = "800px" dur = "3" fill = "hold">
</t:animate>
</SPAN>-->
<t:img src = "p2.JPG"></t:img>
</t:par>
<t:par dur = "3" timeAction = "display">
<!--<SPAN class="time uaic">Universitatea "Al. I. Cuza"
<t:animatecolor attributeName = "color" from = "white" to = "gold" begin = "1" dur = "3" fill = "hold">
</t:animatecolor>
</SPAN>-->
<t:img src = "p3.JPG"></t:img>
</t:par>
<t:par dur = "3" timeAction = "display">
<t:img src = "p4.JPG"></t:img>
</t:par>
</t:seq>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get this code working,but pressing the button does nothing,i can't see anything wrong with the code.                                                                         I've tried changing the pictures, but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't XHTML. It is "Something like XHTML which is missing its namespace declaration" + "TIME".

See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533117(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This topic documents a feature of HTML+TIME 2.0, which is obsolete as of Windows Internet Explorer 9.

You are using an obsolete tool that was never supported in anything other than Internet Explorer.

You need to find an entirely different approach.